# Pandas - cohorting in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

new to pandas. I am trying to do some cohort analysis on client usage data where the values are stored by calendar date but I want to analyze by the "start" date of that client. The dataframe contains zeroes before that client's start date.

This is what the data looks like:

```
          2014-06-01 2014-07-01 2014-08-01 2014-09-01 2014-10-01 2014-11-01  \
100003211          0          0          0          0          0          0   
100000006          0          0          0          0         88        334   
100000018          0          0        332          0          0          0   
100000019          0          0          0        138        177          6   
100000023        558        179        243          0          0          0   
100000035          0          0        115          1          0          0
```

The mental image I have for what I'm trying to do is strip the zeroes in each row up to the leftmost non-zero value, and then "left align" that row. Each row would start with a nonzero number and then proceed as before.

This is the loop I've tried to process from the above dataframe into a "cohorted" dataframe:

```
for client_id,row in df_raw.iterrows():
    while not row.empty and row[:0] == 0:
        row.pop(0)
    df_cohorted[client_id] = row
```

...but I'm getting this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Meanwhile, this doesn't even seem like the right approach. From reading other topics it seems like I may want to transpose and then use a mapping function?

Any suggestions welcome, either to use a different approach or (if my approach is best) to help identify what's ailing.

EDIT

Output would hopefully look something like this. The columns would indicate the 1st nonzero month of data for each row, the 2nd would be the calendar month following it, etc.

```
            1st  2nd  3rd  4th  5th  6th
100003211     0    0    0    0    0    0   
100000006    88  334   
100000018   332    0    0    0   
100000019   138  177    6   
100000023   558  179  243    0    0    0   
100000035   115    1    0    0
```

Comment: If you "left align" the rows won't that mess up your columns?

Comment: Also, I believe you are getting the `ValueError` because of `row[:0] == 0`, you are slicing the entire row (which is already being done with `iterrows` whereas I am assuming you are trying to access just one element at a time within that row. Hence its suggestion to use `row.item()`.

Comment: Re messing up columns, in the cohorted dataframe the columns would be 1st Month, 2nd Month, 3rd Month, etc.

Comment: I would suggest perhaps giving an example with some sample data of what you are wanting your `df_cohorted` to look like.

Comment: Edited description to add example desired output

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding what you are attempting to do, but I don't see how the desired output is valid since the starting month of `100000006` and `100000018` for example are different so how can they be in the same '1st` month column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started with this dataframe

```
           2014-06-01   2014-07-01  2014-08-01  2014-09-01  2014-10-01  2014-11-01
100003211   0           0           0           0           0           0
100000006   0           0           0           0           88          334
100000018   0           0           332         0           0           0
100000019   0           0           0           138         177         6
100000023   558         179         243         0           0           0
100000035   0           0           115         1           0           0
```

and defining this function

```
def getLeftAlignSeries(s):      
   a = np.array(np.trim_zeros(s),'f')
   b = np.pad(a,(0,(len(s) - len(a))),mode='constant',constant_values=0)     
   return b
```

Then an Apply()

```
dfNew = df.apply(getLeftAlignSeries,axis=1)    
dfNew   

            2014-06-01  2014-07-01  2014-08-01  2014-09-01  2014-10-01  2014-11-01
100003211   0           0           0           0           0           0
100000006   88          334         0           0           0           0
100000018   332         0           0           0           0           0
100000019   138         177         6           0           0           0
100000023   558         179         243         0           0           0
100000035   115         1           0           0           0           0
```

Comment: AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'pad'", u'occurred at index 100003211')

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had the following import statement.  Import numpy as np

Comment: Yep have that, otherwise it would have failed on the 'np' with NameError: ("global name 'np' is not defined", u'occurred at index 100003211')

Comment: Hmm, I'm on numpy 1.6.2 and the current version looks like 1.9. And, it looks like pad was added in 1.7. There's the problem.

Comment: Yep, upgrade or do the padding yourself

Comment: apply() with trimming and custom padding worked perfectly. Thank you! The apply() approach was exactly what I was looking for instead of a loop approach.